# Pass Argument to Script Stored Procedure using Command Line

Tags: sql, mysql, bash, stored-procedures

I wish to pass an argument to an SQL script which has a stored procedure.

An example of the invocation is

```
mysql -sN -h db.com -u myUser -p -D myDb -e "set @v_db_name='myDb'; \\. script.sql"
```

And the script.sql is

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myDB.proc//

CREATE PROCEDURE myDB.proc(IN @v_db_name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    SELECT concat('Debug v_db_name : ', @v_db_name);
END //

delimiter ;

CALL myDB.proc();
```

And that generates error

```
ERROR 1193 (HY000) at line 1: Unknown system variable 'v_db_name'
```

Any tips or pointers would be much appreciated.

## Working Example

Thank you for the input on this, combining your ideas, resulted in this working solution

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myDB.proc//

CREATE PROCEDURE myDB.proc(IN v_db_name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    SELECT concat('Debug v_db_name : ', v_db_name);
END //

delimiter ;

CALL myDB.proc(@v_db_name);
```

Executed via

```
mysql -sN -h db.com -u myUser -p -D myDb -e "set @v_db_name='myDb'; \\. script.sql"
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `@` variables as procedure parameters in MySQL. Get rid of the `@` character in the parameter list and the query.

Comment: Tip: use `source` instead of `.` to read the script. These are synonym [commands in the mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html), but `source` doesn't need any backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the `@` sigil on local variables in procedures.

MySQL has two different types of variables:

- Local variables for stored routines, which do not have the `@` sigil. These include arguments to stored procedures or stored functions, and local variables created in the body of those routines with `DECLARE`.
- User-defined variables which have the `@` sigil. You don't use `DECLARE` to create these variables, they are created implicitly when you assign a value to them.

  You don't need to make an argument to your procedure for these variables to be visible. They are visible throughout your session, and they are not local to the stored procedure.

  I don't call them global variables, because MySQL uses that term for a different concept, but user variables are at least global to all procedures within the user's session.

If your procedure takes an argument, you must pass an argument when you use `CALL`. In that case, the argument would not use the sigil, but the reference to the user variable when you `CALL` would use the sigil:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myDB.proc//

CREATE PROCEDURE myDB.proc(IN v_db_name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    SELECT concat('Debug v_db_name : ', v_db_name);
END //

delimiter ;

CALL myDB.proc(@v_db_name);
```

In fact, `v_db_name` (the local variable in the procedure) and `@v_db_name` (the user variable) are totally different variables, despite their similar name. In other words, they can have different values.

You might want to name them differently to avoid confusion.

You could alternatively make a procedure that uses a user variable, but does not take an argument. Then you don't need to pass the argument when you use `CALL`.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myDB.proc//

CREATE PROCEDURE myDB.proc()
BEGIN
    SELECT concat('Debug v_db_name : ', @v_db_name);
END //

delimiter ;

CALL myDB.proc();
```

Either way, when you `CALL` a procedure, you must pass exactly the same number of arguments as the procedure expects in its defined argument list. [MySQL unfortunately still doesn't support optional arguments for procedures](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15975).